# How to design an air core transformer to operate in audio frequency range (20 Hz to 20 kHz)

Tags: audio, transformer

Impedance matching has become a very annoying problem for me in my project of designing an audio amplifier. Here in my locality, audio frequency transformers are not available. I've browsed for possible alternatives online. Emitter follower is a good idea but it is not much efficient.

I found an article on the internet about DIY construction of air core transformers. However it was stated in the design that it was intended for radio frequencies.

Now I would like to extend the design for audio frequency application. My only constraint is that I do not have any material for the core. Hence it has to be air core. Please guide me with design steps.

Comment: Why is impedance matching a problem for you? They are not needed or wanted in an audio amplifier unless perhaps you are designing with ancient technology like tubes.

Comment: i am designing using transistors.

Comment: Why impedance matching is the problem to you? What are the two things you  going to match?

Comment: the output of the amplifier with an 8 ohm speaker.

Comment: You are designing a solid state amplifier to drive an 8 Ω speaker? I'll reiterate what others have said: you don't need a transformer. Take a look at any solid state audio amp, there aren't output transformers. Also, what do you think your output impedance is, anyway?

Comment: @uint128_t: As a matter of fact i do need one. i am designing the amplifier using discrete components for my project.

Comment: In that case, you're doing it wrong. Show us your design. But in any case, building an air-core transformer for 20 Hz is completely impractical. You would need too many turns of wire to get a useful level of inductance, and the resulting resistance would make it useless for the low impedances you're targeting.

Comment: @SoumyaSambeetMohapatra So _your_ solid state amplifier with discrete components needs impedance matching, but everyone else doesn't need it? You're not _supposed_ to match the speaker impedance to your amplifier.

Comment: @SoumyaSambeetMohapatra Please explain _why_ you need this. And as Dave Tweed has pointed out, an air-core transformer at 20 Hz is not going to work very well. Also, look at Digikey and Mouser to get an idea of the size and typical behaviour of 20-20k Hz transformers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A modern audio amplifier is essentially a variable bipolar power supply with an output impedance very close to zero ohms (a voltage source) with its output voltage controlled by an AC input signal, the audio source.

As such, the impedance of the load is irrelevant since the amplifier will supply whatever current the load requires, based on the load's impedance and how much power the amplifier can supply.

For example, let's say we have an amplifier which was optimized to drive an 8 ohm load, cranked, and is specified to output 100 watts, CW,  into that load.

That means that since \$P =\frac{E^2}{R}\$, the voltage across the load will be about 28 volts, and the current through the load will be about 3.5 amperes, both RMS.

That also means that a load with an impedance higher than 8 ohms won't dissipate 100 watts because the amplifier can only output 28 volts, and a load lower than 8 ohms will bog the amplifier down.

Do you get any of this?

Answer (score 2):

You have all the correct advice in your comments.

I know how boring it can be to have lots of people tell you what to do, so I'm going to tell you why.

As it doesn't sound like you know what you're doing, I'm going to assume you are designing a lowish power amplifier, in the 10 watt or so range.

For 8watts rms into an 8ohm speaker, you will want 8 volts rms and 1 amp rms. The peaks will be sqrt(2) higher. This will need a 30 volt or so supply, with transistors capable of 1.5A or more.

Now this is exactly where low/medium power transistors 'like' to operate. Go to an online catalogue and search on 50v 3A transistors and above. There are gazillions of the things, at very good prices.

If you wanted to make an amplifier suited to a much higher impedance, hundreds of volts at hundreds of mA, or to a much lower impedance, a few volts at 10s of amps, you *could*, but it would be hard, unusual work. It is so much easier to design one suited for an 8ohm load.

Answer (score 2):

No. There are no "air core audio transformers" because it is not possible to make a *practical* air core transformer that will operate at such very low frequencies as audio (20KHz and below).

Since you offer no details, it is difficult to understand why...

> Impedance matching has become a very annoying problem for me in my project of designing an audio amplifier.

It makes us think that you don't understand the problem and you are attempting to use the wrong solution.